# How to subtract 1 from each value in a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I think this should be a simple problem, but I can't find a solution.

Within a subset of rows in a dataframe, I need to decrement the value of each item in a column by 1. 
I have tried various approaches, but the values continue to be unchanged. 
Following another entry on SO, I tried

```
def minus1(x):
    x =x-1
    return x

pledges[pledges.Source == 'M0607'].DayOFDrive = pledges[pledges.Source == 'M0607'].DayOFDrive.map(minus1)
```

When I typed

```
pledges[pledges.Source == 'M0607'].DayOFDrive
```

to check it, the original unchanged data came back. 
I have also tried

```
pledges[pledges.Source == 'M0607'].DayOFDrive = pledges[pledges.Source == 'M0607'].DayOFDrive-1
```

which also does nothing.

How can I reduce all the values in a column by 1 for a subset of rows ?

Answer (score 3):

If this returns the data you want to modify:

```
pledges[pledges.Source == 'M0607'].DayOFDrive
```

Then try modifying it this way:

```
pledges[pledges.Source == 'M0607'].DayOFDrive -= 1
```

Comment: I did try that and it didn't work.  I solved it by reconstructing the dataframe from scratch, but still I would like to figure out the way to do this.

Comment: Looks promising. I will try it out later. Thanks!